# Disable logging messages from imported libraries

Tags: python, logging

I am facing an issue with logging.

In my project, the logging file is bloated with so many log messages from imported libraries. I do not want to see them at all in the log file. This is (below code block) how the logging file settings are setup. I am not familiar with the logging library as I have not used it before. Goggling around, I found the same suggestion repeated on several threads..

```
logger.getLogger("MODULE_name_which_you_dont_want_to_See_in_logs").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

However, this does not solve my problem. Can someone help me out here please?
This is how my logging to file is setup at the moment:

```
# Define logging settings and path for saving log
logger.define_logging(
    logpath=path_output_folder,
    logfile=LOGFILE,
    file_level=logging.DEBUG,
    screen_level=screen_level,
)
```

I have many imported libraries, but I suspect the culprits to be dash and requests. I added statements for them, but still the file is bloated.

```
logger.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger.getLogger("dash").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

A sample of the unwanted log messages:

```
2020-12-16 14:01:44,111 - DEBUG - PngImagePlugin - STREAM b'IHDR' 16 13
2020-12-16 14:01:44,112 - DEBUG - PngImagePlugin - STREAM b'PLTE' 41 456
2020-12-16 14:01:44,112 - DEBUG - PngImagePlugin - STREAM b'IDAT' 509 5012
2020-12-16 14:01:57,455 - DEBUG - selector_events - Using selector: EpollSelector
2020-12-16 14:01:59,079 - DEBUG - protocol - client - state = CONNECTING
2020-12-16 14:01:59,080 - DEBUG - protocol - client - event = connection_made(<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=15 read=idle write=<idle, bufsize=0>>)
2020-12-16 14:01:59,082 - DEBUG - client - client > GET /devtools/browser/0a792431-cccb-4598-b081-92a9306f77ca HTTP/1.1
2020-12-16 14:01:59,082 - DEBUG - client - client > Headers([('Host', '127.0.0.1:39637'), ('Upgrade', 'websocket'), ('Connection', 'Upgrade'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Key', 'IlrPj2gl6wjO42IIFPyrXg=='), ('Sec-WebSocket-Version', '13'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions', 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits'), ('User-Agent', 'Python/3.8 websockets/8.1')])
2020-12-16 14:01:59,082 - DEBUG - protocol - client - event = data_received(<211 bytes>)
2020-12-16 14:01:59,083 - DEBUG - client - client < HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
2020-12-16 14:01:59,083 - DEBUG - client - client < Headers([('Upgrade', 'WebSocket'), ('Connection', 'Upgrade'), ('Sec-WebSocket-Accept', 'mJN4dKj9ta6vs7uHbbdBZ0y5tSc='), ('Sec-WebSocket-Extensions', 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits=15')])
2020-12-16 14:01:59,083 - DEBUG - protocol - client - state = OPEN
2020-12-16 14:01:59,084 - DEBUG - protocol - client > Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"id": 1, "method": "Target.setDiscoverTargets", "params": {"discover": true}}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
2020-12-16 14:01:59,084 - DEBUG - protocol - client - event = data_received(<175 bytes>)
2020-12-16 14:01:59,084 - DEBUG - protocol - client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"F61E36583DEF4DF0A2A1B7320D3D848B","type":"page","title":"","url":"about:blank","attached":false,"browserContextId":"D249088AE5A6F231C6D6C385CDB0C54E"}}}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
2020-12-16 14:01:59,085 - DEBUG - protocol - client - event = data_received(<127 bytes>)
2020-12-16 14:01:59,085 - DEBUG - protocol - client < Frame(fin=True, opcode=1, data=b'{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"d9767b47-b4ff-4641-919e-97b5924ab80f","type":"browser","title":"","url":"","attached":false}}}', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
```

Comment: Can you show some messages you would like to not see? The code you are showing us is probably fine in isolation but you need to add `setLevel` for the correct modules, and/or make sure you `setLevel` after they have been initialized, but before you call them.

Comment: @tripleee I added some of the log messages I see in the question now. By "make sure you setLevel after they have been initialized" you mean after I import them in the respect .py modules ?

Comment: `PngImagePlugin` is certainly neither part of `requests` nor `dash`; it seems to be from Pillow. The others look like `urllib3` (or some other `urllib` perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is twofold: first log messages propagate up the logging hierarchy irrespective of logger levels, propagated messages only care for the level of the handlers. To stop this you can just stop the propagation from the loggers that you don't want to see:

```
logger.getLogger("requests").propagate = False
```

The second problem is that you are probably not getting the right loggers. Most of the verbose output from requests is actually from `urllib` which is used by requests. You will want to also stop the propagation on that logger:

```
logging.getLogger("urllib3").propagate = False
```

Edit: looking at your code you are using a `logger.define_logging` call, which is not part of the python logging stdlib. If you are using a third-party logging helper all bets are off in term of what might actually be happening with your logging setup and usually it is not required.

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks good- and this is the appropriate way to affect the level of specific modules.

If you don't want to see warning, you might consider moving to only showing error messages:

```
logger.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.getLogger("dash").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Although it's good practice **make sure you understand you know what the warnings are before you turn them off**. I've genuinely worked with people who have ignored depreciation warnings, only to find that their code stops functioning after the next update!

Also, you can change levels on mass with your logger setup:

```
# Define logging settings and path for saving log
logger.define_logging(
    logpath=path_output_folder,
    logfile=LOGFILE,
    file_level=logging.WARNING,
    screen_level=screen_level,
    )
```

In case it's also handy, here are your options for levels (in order of severity):
*CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG, NOTSET*

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, even when I set it to WARNING or ERROR, I still end up seeing so many DEBUG messages from random imported libraries. 

I can't use logging.WARNING en masse (i.e., within define_logging function) as I want to see my own INFO messages when running the code. 

Thanks for the tip about when to turn off messages.